# Visual Code wont open from explorer or command prompt

Tags: visual-studio-code

I had to re-install Visual Code and now found i cant open visual code from explorer window or from command prompt
I cant get the shell command to appear in the palette command to run
Install 'code' command in PATH
any ideas on whats gone wrong
thanks

Comment: What OS are you using? Which error raised...? Please more information.

Comment: Its Windows 10, theres no error message - I just cant open VC from windows exployer or command prompt